# Im trying to find if a member in the server has a specific role and then remove the role from him but i dont know how, here's the code:

Tags: discord.py, bots

```
@client.command()
async def find(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles,name="Palpatin")
    for member in guild.members:
        if role in member.roles :
            await ctx.send(f'{member}')
            await member.remove_roles(role)
```

When I try to use the code there are no errors but the bot doesn't send what member has the role either removes the role from that member

Comment: Can you print the `role` on console?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Check role is not `None`

Comment: ```@client.command()
async def find(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Palpatin")
    if role == None : 
        await ctx.send("boooooo")
    else: 
        for member in guild.members:
            if role in member.roles :
                await ctx.send(f'{member}')
                await member.remove_roles(role)```
Like that?

Comment: what Weylyn is asking is to `print(role)` directly after declaration

Answer (score 0):

As @Weylyn said, your variable `role` might be `None` if there is no role named exactly `Palpatin`, if that is the case, your if will always be evaluated to `False` since `None in` any list will always be False, this might be why you do not get any message nor any error.

Also, your `for` might not work if you do not have the member intents enabled (check here https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html )